# Check multiple url from csv if valid or not, using python

Tags: python, csv, url

I have this script works if I hard code the link in script itself. But wish to take multiple urls from a csv file having this column say url_to_check, need to validate all of them one by one if these urls are valid or not. Please help. Thanks

```
import httplib 
from urlparse import urlparse 

def checkUrl(url):
    p = urlparse(url)
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(p.netloc)
    conn.request('HEAD', p.path)
    resp = conn.getresponse()
    return resp.status < 400 

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    print checkUrl('http://www.stackoverflow.com')
```

Comment: python has a module `csv` for dealing with csv file.

Comment: Are you looking for help with the validation, or just in parsing the csv file for the urls to pass to your function? As far as I can tell, your function is working fine except you need to catch `IOError`s and return `False`, such as the `socket.gaierror`'s that might be thrown if the url netloc is invalid upon request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python's [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#reader-objects) module for parsing your csv file.

A simple example using your example column name and `checkUrl` function:

```
import csv
with open('/path/to/your/csv/file') as fobj:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fobj)
    for row in reader:
        valid = checkUrl(row['url_to_check'])
        print('%s is %svalid' % (row['url_to_check'], '' if valid else 'in'))
```